# Trouble with file-cache

Tags: helm-for-files

I am using `filecache` as a source to `helm-for-files` because it ends up being faster than using something like `helm-ls-git`(EDITED) or `helm-projectile`. This approach works fine till the cache has around 16000 files. On trying to append another list of around 2000 files, I see emacs memory usage spike until it gets terminated by the OS. At around a file-cache of 16000 file names, the mem usage is around 400mb(that's the gc-limit I have set). On adding these 2000 more files, it hits 10gb and gets killed, since thats the value of `ulimit -v`. This sounds very much like a bug. Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Could you use the profiler (`M-x profiler-start` and `M-x profiler-report`) to try and see where all that time (and memory) is spent?  It's probably a naive algorithmic error.

Answer (score 3):

Projectile can cache if you enable it with `(setq projectile-enable-caching t)`. After caching is enabled and after you open the file list with `helm-projectile-find-file`/`projectile-find-file` for **once**, the subsequent invocations gives you the list instanly (~1 second). It works with the Linux kernel source tree with more than 36000 files. My work laptop is using an average hard drive with only 5400 RPM, the [MKxx65GSX Hard Disk Drive](http://storage.toshiba.com/storagesolutions/archived-models/mkxx65gsx-series). Here is [its ranking](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd.php?hdd=TOSHIBA+MK3265GS). Not very impressive, as you can see, and the first invocation of `helm-projectile-find-file` took around ~3 seconds on it, including ignoring files and sorting files.

I tried once with my home directory that contains 100k files and `git init` it. It took quite a while to retrieve the files, but once the files are retrieved and cached, subsequent invocations of `helm-projectile-find-file` happens instantly, with no lag when entering pattern and get results immediately. This is just a test and I don't use Projectile with my home directory though.

Finally, there was no memory spike as you suggested because essentially Projectile only stores file list as plain text and does some fancy text processing to manipulate the list.

**EDIT**: `helm-git` is an old package (from 2012). If you want real speed, use `helm-ls-git` that is created from Helm maintainer. It is fast because essentially it only retrieve the list of files from the command `git ls-files` without fancy processing like removing ignore files and sorting files and create directory list. Took ~1 second on the Linux source tree to for `helm-ls-git` command to present me the file list. `helm-projectile-find-file` needs more time because it does more, but you are compensated by its caching.

Comment: Yes, I was using `helm-ls-git`. I keep forgetting which ones newer :)

Comment: So, how things work for you now?

Comment: About `projectile`, I followed your guide to using it with `helm`(brilliant guides btw!) and ran into an issue with `helm-projectile` on the first run. Never went back to it after.

Comment: What was the issue may I know?

Comment: Btw, I tried breaking up that list of 2000 files I mentioned in the question into lists of 200 each. This ended up working. I memory usage suddenly spike up after the filecache became large enough. But after the processing finished, it would fall back. This behaviour does sound like a bug. Will try to report it when possible.

Comment: Oh the issue was the one you mentioned - the first run takes a lot of time. I think I waited for around 20 minutes on my work repo and gave up.

Comment: Strange. What is your OS? On Windows, it took me 6 seconds; on Ubuntu, it took me 3 seconds, and on my MacbookAir at home with SSD, it took less than 1 second to get the file list for the Linux source tree (more than 36k files) using Helm Projectile/Projectile. Probably something incorrectly configured?

Comment: Probably there was a bug back then but it should be fixed now. Maybe it will work for you now if you try the current latest Projectile + Helm Projectile. I'm pretty sure anything less than 50k should not be a problem with Helm Projectile.

Comment: Just a note to anyone read the above comment: the statistics I provided for getting file list above is done **without caching**. With caching enable, everything should be less than 1 second.